# How to tell if two sets are independent?

Tags: probability

If I have two holes which release letters from the alphabet. The first hole can release a letter from {a,b,c,d} and the second hole {e,f,g,h}. The holes release the letters at the same time

I observe that after 7 releases, the combinations of release observed are {(b,h), (d,g), (a,g), (b,e), (b,f), (c,g), (b,g)). Is it possible to determine if there is some relationship between the releases, i.e are the two holes release letters independent of one another based on what we have seen in the 7 observations?

Comment: There are only seven observations, which is not nearly enough for statistical significance.

Comment: If we had 1000's of observations what would be the technique to observe if the two releases are working independently or not? And would that technique not apply to (with substantially less accuracy) with lower numbers of observations

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Testing_for_statistical_independence

Comment: Thankyou. Apologies for asking such basic questions

Comment: No reason to apologize!